# How to iterate a Map<List, String>?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to iterate a `Map` of `Map<List, String>`? 
I wanna know how to list all values, and find a key: `[1, 'A']`.

```
void main() {
  print(_mapList.map);
  //??
  // _mapList.map((i, s) =>{

  // });
}

Map<List, String> _mapList = {
  [1, 'A']: "1A",
  [2, 'B']: "2A"
};
```

Comment: `_mapList.entries` will give you a list (well, an `Iterable`) of key-value pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways that you can do it. I will give 2 examples;

```
_mapList.forEach((key, value) {
  print(key);
  print(value);
});

for (var key in _mapList.keys) {
  print(key);
  print(_mapList[key]);
}
```

you can use `map` if you want to transform your map to another type;

```
_mapList.map((key, value) {
  print(key);
  print(value);
  return MapEntry("transformed_key", "transformed_value");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can you add an example using map? _mapList.map

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Check out my answer

Comment: if you don't need to transform your data, don't use map. Anyway I edited the answer to be another example

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it using `.map`, here's how you'd do:

```
_mapList.map((key, value) {
  print(key);
  print(value);
  return null;
});
```